# Where are the index files of Zend Lucene?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-lucene

the first time I indexed my data this way

```
$index = new Zend_Search_Lucene('/tmp/search_index', true);
```

This created a tmp/search_index folder in the public folder of my project. After I noticed there is something wrong with the index I just deleted all file in the search_index folder.

After trying to reindex the data I realized that the search_index folder is empty. However the search gives still results. Where is the index data stored now? It's not in the public folder...

Comment: Did you look in the `/tmp/search_index` folder (not in your project, but the system root)?

Comment: actually I have no root access, do you think it might be there? How would I create the index in the public folder?

Comment: You probably *do* have access to the `/tmp` folder. Specify the path properly, `/tmp/` is an absolute path pointing to the system `/tmp` folder...

Comment: actually you were right, the tmp was in the root folder. Post this as answer and I will except it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/tmp/search_index` refers to the *system root `/tmp` folder*. Use some other path relative to your app, like `tmp/search_index`.